# Rest Server-Client

Tags: java, json, rest, soapui

I implemented a Rest Service for a Wildfly Server,

How do I send a User with a Rest Client as JSON, im using SoapUi,
to test the Service?

```
@POST
@Path("register")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User register(User user){
    return callloggerManagementBean.register(user);
        }
```

Comment: Please check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XV7WW0bDy9c